# Python regex - Problems with start and end tags

Tags: python, regex, tags

I have a string with makeshift start/end tags.

It's something like this:

`"<Hello>Dog<Bye> <Hello>Cat<Bye>"`

I in this string I want to match `'Dog'` and `'Cat'`, but since I'm not good with regex, this is all I've come up with:

```
re.findall(r'<Hello>(.+)<Bye>', mystring)
```

The only match I get with this, is:

```
'Dog<Bye> <Hello>Cat'
```

Which I guess is pretty obvious...

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Gah, I closed this for `*?` instead of `+?`. It's basically the same thing, but I need to be more careful with my new close-as-duplicate superpowers.

Comment: @Veedrac particularly because the OP seems to be trying to parse some sort of XML using regex. The correct answer to that is [`"Don't do it, use an XML parser"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and *not* `"use non-greedy quantifiers"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `.*?` version which is the non-greedy quantifier and will match as little as possible:

```
re.findall(r'<Hello>(.+?)<Bye>', mystring)
```

Gives:

`'Dog'` and `'Cat'`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I thought I had actually used that one, yielding no results, but when I tried again after reading your reply, I realized I'd just made a typo the last time.

Comment: @Yngve, Glad I could help. If it was sufficient, please consider accepting my answer. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but have to wait a couple of minutes :D